# how python handle parametric polymorphic function?

Tags: python, generics, polymorphic-functions

- I tried to discover polymorphic sum function in python for 5 variable types : *str*, *int*, *float*, *complex*, *bool*.

Here it's the **working solution** i found:

```
sum("W", "T", "F") #return WTF
sum(1, 2, 3) #return 6

@staticmethod
def sum(a: None, b: None, c: None) -> object:         
    return a + b + c
```

- I tried **two other ways**, but they don't work as expected.

**First way**, Python don't recognize the type :
It just calls the last sum function and return error

```
sum("W", "T", "F") #*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'*

@staticmethod
def sum(*args: str) -> str:
    sum_str = ""
    for el_str in args:
        sum_str = sum_str + el_str
    return sum_str
@staticmethod
def sum(*args: int) -> int:
    sum = 0
    for el_int in args:
        sum += el_int
    return sum
@staticmethod    
def sum(*args: float) -> float:
    sum = 0
    for el_float in args:
        sum += el_float
    return sum
@staticmethod        
def sum(*args: complex) -> complex:
    sum = 0
    for el_complex in args:
        sum += el_complex
    return sum
@staticmethod
def sum(*args: bool) -> bool:
    sum = 0
    for el_bool in args:
        sum += el_bool
    return sum
```

**Second way**, it partially works but I can't support *str* and *number* at the same time.

```
sum("W", "T", "F") #return WTF
sum(1, 2, 3) #return 6

def sum_generic(*args: T) :
    sum_gen = 0 #sum_gen = ""
    for el in args:
        sum_gen = sum_gen + el
    return sum_gen
```

Questions:

- Why first way doesn't work as expected?
- In the second way, how can I assign the right type to sum_gen ? Like sum_gen: type(args[0])

Comment: Because every time you define a function with the same.name it overwrites the previous function. Python does not support method/function overloading. Type annotations are simply for type hints, they don't have runtime effects

Comment: Thanks it's clear but it does not answer me about the second way. I mean how can i handle generic types with 'number' and 'string' in one function ?

Comment: What do you mean? You are going to have to check the types and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Also, why on earth are you decorating regular functions wiht `staticmethod`???

Comment: i meant like don't check the type and let the language do the job, like in typescript for instance.

Comment: I used @staticmethod ... first because they are in object class and are called by CLASS_Name.function. in addition, they don't use class attribute. I understand static like Java define static function.

Comment: Oh my goodness, what's wrong with it @juanpa ?

Comment: I as explained already, Python doesn't support this. You are asking for what is called *ad-hoc polymorphism*, (not parametric polymorphism) and in the OOP context, this is usually just referred to as *method/function overloading*.  In any case, Python doesn't support it. You have to  build your own dispatch table, or maybe use the built-in `functools.singledispatch` or `functools.singledispatchmethod`

Comment: 'dispatch' is what i need. Thanks for your explanations.